# proxy forwarding

Tags: linux, proxy, socks

I have 10 socks5 proxys and I want to make a Linux server to connect to (use as a proxy) and connect me to one of the socks. The connection should be random. Any ideas how to do this?
Squid isn't a solution because it doesn't work with socks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like balance http://www.inlab.de/balance.html on your "server in the middle" so you'll have a socks listening port which balances on the 10 destination socks server you have, it should work as soon as you ask balance to keep source host X always on the same socks until he fails.